Seeding value in PHP
I was going through this article
https://www.ambionics.io/blog/php-mt-rand-prediction
which claims that if we use mt_rand(), we can get the seed value using two values instead of brute forcing.
In the article it says

The first step in generating random numbers using mt_rand() is to use a seed, an unsigned int, to generate a state array of 624 values. This is done by either calling mt_srand($seed) or automatically, by PHP, upon requesting the first random number. After this, each call to mt_rand() will take the next state value, scramble it, and return it to the user.

My question : Is the mt_rand() completely insecure or it is platform dependent as well? For example when I will do mt_rand(),the seeding state array of 624 values will be created in my computer is different. if Person B does mt_rand() with same seeding value the output state will be different. How come than we both get the same random number?

Mersenne-Twister "is not cryptographically secure, unless the CryptMT variant (discussed below) is used. The reason is that observing a sufficient number of iterations (624 in the case of MT19937, since this is the size of the state vector from which future iterations are produced) allows one to predict all future iterations." (source).

@Olivier the state vector is different in each computer correct?

The seed sets the initial state vector. If you use the same seed, you have the same initial state, and you generate the same sequence.

Yes, mt_rand() is completely insecure.

Protip: If you are looking at a PHP doc page and it has a yellow or red box that says "Caution" or "Warning" you should read the contents of that box carefully before continuing. For example, the one on the doc page for mt_rand() that explains and answers your question.

Seeding means providing the initial state. Every time you seed with the same number, you will get the same set of pseudo-random numbers, no matter what machine you run it on. You can think of it as performing a series of complex math operations on a given input number.
mt_rand() is a pseudo-random number generator. This means it doesn't generate truly random numbers; it only generates ones that look random. The process is completely reversible and reproducible. For this reason, it is not cryptographically secure.
If you want a cryptographically secure value use random_bytes() or the Random\Engine\Secure class.
